# Finding the Jacobian matrix of an intergral

Tags: calculus, integration, matrices, matrix-calculus, jacobian

How do I find the Jacobian matrix of $I : \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ at $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty) ) $
with 
$$I(x,t) := \int_{0}^{x(4t)^{-1/2}} f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s. $$

Comment: Your function supposedly depends on both $x$ and $t$ but as written it only depends on $t$

Comment: sorry i tried to edit it bit managed to ruin it,  the bounds on the integral are supposed to be x/((sqrt)4t) and 0

Comment: I think I fixed it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but let's try!
First, we supose your $f$ is a continuous function.
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus give us:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}I(x,t) = f(\sqrt(4t))  $$
The Jacobian matrix of $I(x,t)$ is

$$J[I] = [\frac{\partial I(x,t)}{\partial x} \quad  \frac{\partial I(x,t)}{\partial t}] $$

So
$$J[I] = [\frac{\partial I(x,t)}{\partial x} \quad f(\sqrt(4t)) ] $$

But $I$ doens`t depends of $x$, so $\frac{\partial I(x,t)}{\partial x} = 0$

So we have
$$J[I] = [0 \quad f(\sqrt(4t)) ] .$$

Comment: The question was edited to include $x$ in the expression